# Как сделать приложение одиночка?

Tags: c++, qt

Как сделать приложение одиночка средствами Qt5+ под Windows (xp, 7, 8, 10) ?
Чтобы нельзя было запустить два экземпляра одновременно.

Comment: Что такое "приложение одиночка" в вашем понимании?

Comment: Чтобы нельзя было запустить два экземпляра одновременно

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте уточнения в вопрос (кнопка "править")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Файл блокировки

*Файл будет удалён автоматически*
Каждый пользователь может запустить свою версию.

```
#include <QString>
#include <QLockFile>
#include <QDir>
#include <QMessageBox>

QString tmpDir = QDir::tempPath();
QLockFile lockFile(tmpDir + "/<unique identifier>.lock");

if(!lockFile.tryLock(100)){
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
    msgBox.setText("You already have this app running."
                    "\r\nOnly one instance is allowed.");
    msgBox.exec();
    return 1;
}
```

## Семафоры и разделяемая память

Уникальный инстанс приложения на всю машину

```
QSystemSemaphore sema("<unique identifier>", 1);
    sema.acquire();

#ifndef Q_OS_WIN32
    // в Unix разделяемая память не чистится при креше
    // Очищаем, если осталась от предыдущих запусков
    QSharedMemory nix_fix_shmem("<unique identifier 2>");
    if(nix_fix_shmem.attach()){
        nix_fix_shmem.detach();
    }
#endif

    QSharedMemory shmem("<unique identifier 2>");
    bool is_running;
    if (shmem.attach()){
        is_running = true;
    }else{
        shmem.create(1);
        is_running = false;
    }
    sema.release();

    if(is_running){
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Warning);
        msgBox.setText("You already have this app running."
                        "\r\nOnly one instance is allowed.");
        msgBox.exec();
        return 1;
    }
```